# Spring authentication, does it use encrypted cookies?

Tags: java, spring

Does the [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) use (or in one of the options that it supports) encrypted cookies that store the logged in users userId in a cookie?

This is how ASP.NET authentication works, where it encrypts a value in a cookie, which is normally the userId or username.

Is that what Spring does? (I realize Spring let you choose, but is this the most common approach generally?)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the source handy to prove this, but the answer to the question is no.

Spring Security handles everything on the server side. The only cookie on the client is the one for JSESSIONID, and the security framework merely checks for the authentication/principal object in the request's session (at least under the default setup).

I don't understand why you would store any sort of authentication information in the client's cookie if you could simply store a sessionID and track authentication details and state on the server side.

Comment: sessions are bound to a specific server.

Comment: and a load balancer with sticky sessions makes that a moot point

Comment: true, but who wants sticky sessions if you have other options.

Comment: people that don't want to put user information in cookies or worry about encryption :) or apps that need to maintain state during a user's session.

Comment: Ok, and if you want to restart just this one server in a cluster behind a load balancer? Can you accept forcing users of your system to relogin in the middle of whatever they where just doing. No? Well, then let's just add a persistent storage. And replication for it. And hit it on every user request. And introduce even more complexity into the system. Point being: presenting the decision to use server-side state as the most obvious and simple option does not quite reflect the reality.

Comment: @AlexFedulov while I upvoted your comment reading the following on why encrypted-cookies are bad and why Spring will not support them made me change my mind. For a starter it becomes a mess to change the users role and or privileges and while it effectively looks cleaner to scale, sessions can/should be ported to a middleware making the scale point moot.

https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/20/exploiting-encrypted-cookies-for-fun-and-profit

Answer (score -3):

Storing user ID or any kind of data the server relies upon is a *terrible* idea. It typically means as soon as someone figures out how your encryption works (which is only a matter of time, particularly when they have a crib as user IDs tend to be public too) they can probably compromise your system.

In case you're wondering what a "crib" is. see [Cryptography FAQ (03/10: Basic Cryptology)](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/cryptography-faq/part03/):

> Cryptanalytic methods include what is
>   known as `practical cryptanalysis'':
>   the enemy doesn't have to just stare
>   at your ciphertext until he figures
>   out the plaintext. For instance, he
>   might assume`cribs''---stretches of
>   probable plaintext. If the crib is
>   correct then he might be able to
>   deduce the key and then decipher the
>   rest of the message. Or he might
>   exploit ``isologs''---the same
>   plaintext enciphered in several
>   cryptosystems or several keys. Thus he
>   might obtain solutions even when
>   cryptanalytic theory says he doesn't
>   have a chance.

Java Web apps typically just store a session ID and that session on the serverside contains such information as user ID. That's *much* more secure.

Comment: Funny how MS doesn't think so :)  Probably 95% of .net apps store either the user id or username in the cookie!

Comment: do you have a source for this claim?

Comment: If you have a system where the user just needs to figure out a) what encryption algorithm you use (usually pretty obvious) and b) what the encryption key is (for which you may have one or many cribs) in order to log in as anybody then you don't need to prove that system isn't insecure. It's basic commonsense.

Comment: @matt look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx see: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName.Text, false);