# FormsAuthentication and setting the userID/name in an encrypted cookie, security risk?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, cryptography, cookies

Asp.net stores the session in a cookie, thus not having to worry about sessions on the server side (traditionally sessions are stored in a database, and lookups are done via a session ID, which is usually a Guid like string).

In my previous question, I was asking about how a spring application stores/creates sessions etc: [Spring authentication, does it use encrypted cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069392/springs-authentication-does-it-use-encrypted-cookies)

**Cletus pointed out that storing a username/id in a cookie, although encrypted, is a security issue because the would-be-hacker has both the encrypted text, but also the hacker knows what the actual encrypted text is i.e. the userId or username.**

What are you thoughts on this?
I am sure StackOverflow is also using this mechanism, as is **99.9% of asp.net web applications that are using formsauthentication in this manner.
Microsoft's MSDN site itself is filled with examples like:

```
 FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UsernameTextbox.Text, NotPublicCheckBox.Checked);
```

In the above code, the username value is stored in the encrypted cookie.
**actually, I recall that the asp.net website was hacked because the web.config didn't have the Protection=All in the forms authentication tag.**
So is this a real issue?
To repeat what cletus linked to:
In case you're wondering what a "crib" is. see: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/cryptography-faq/part03/

> Cryptanalytic methods include what is
>   known as practical cryptanalysis'':
>   the enemy doesn't have to just stare
>   at your ciphertext until he figures
>   out the plaintext. For instance, he
>   might assumecribs''---stretches of
>   probable plaintext. If the crib is
>   correct then he might be able to
>   deduce the key and then decipher the
>   rest of the message. Or he might
>   exploit ``isologs''---the same
>   plaintext enciphered in several
>   cryptosystems or several keys. Thus he
>   might obtain solutions even when
>   cryptanalytic theory says he doesn't
>   have a chance.**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look into this document: [Improving Web Application Security: Threats and Countermeasures -- Threat Modeling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302419.aspx)

It's a good start point to understand what security risks are involved and how can you mitigate that threats.